# Advanced SQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

```
week      cookie
1         a
1         b
1         c
1         d
2         a 
2         b
3         a
3         c
3         d
```

**This table represent someone visits a website in a particular week.**  Each cookie represents an individual person.  Each entry represent someone visit this site in a particular week.  For example, the last entry means 'd' come to the site in week 3.

**I want to find out how many (same) people keep coming back in the following week, when given a start week to look at.**

For example, if I look at week 1.  I will get result like:

```
1 | 4
2 | 2
3 | 1
```

Because 4 user came in week 1.  Only 2 of them (a,b) came back in week 2.  Only 1 (a) of them came in all of these 3 weeks.

How can I do a select query to find out?  The table will be big: there might be 100 weeks, so I want to find the right way to do it.

Comment: sorry, it might not be so hard for you guys but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Actually this is an interesting problem.  So you are saying given a week number `n`, then for each week number `w > n`, give the count of users visiting in ALL WEEKS `n` through `w` inclusive?  Or visiting in at least `n` and `w` only?

Comment: I mean ALL the weeks.  So for example, I want to check 10 weeks after the 3rd week.  Ｔｈｅ　ｖａｒｉａｂｌｅ　ｏｆ　ｔｈｅ　ｑｕｅｒｙ　ｗｉｌｌ　ｊｕｓｔ　ｂｅ　３　ａｎｄ　１０．　　Ｔｈａｎｋｓ．　ｐｌｅａｓｅ　ｈｅｌｐ．

Comment: Well you're welcome but this one is quite hard.  Do not feel bad that you are stuck. "For alls" are hard in SQL.  I'm working on something....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses variables to track adjacent weeks and work out if they are consecutive:

```
set @start_week = 2, @week := 0, @conseq := 0, @cookie:='';
select conseq_weeks, count(*)
from (
select 
  cookie,
  if (cookie != @cookie or week != @week + 1, @conseq := 0, @conseq := @conseq + 1) + 1 as conseq_weeks,
  (cookie != @cookie and week <= @start_week) or (cookie = @cookie and week = @week + 1) as conseq,
  @cookie := cookie as lastcookie,
  @week := week as lastweek
from (select week, cookie from webhist where week >= @start_week order by 2, 1) x
) y
where conseq
group by 1;
```

This is for week 2. For another week, change the `start_week` variable at the top.

Here's the test:

```
create table webhist(week int, cookie char);
insert into webhist values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'd');
```

Output of above query with `where week >= 1`:

```
+--------------+----------+
| conseq_weeks | count(*) |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 |        4 |
|            2 |        2 |
|            3 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+
```

Output of above query with `where week >= 2`:

```
+--------------+----------+
| conseq_weeks | count(*) |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 |        2 |
|            2 |        1 |
+--------------+----------+
```

p.s. Good question, but a bit of a ball-breaker

Comment: Of Course.  Thanks.   One other thing.  if I　ａｌｓｏ　ｗａｎｔ　ｔｏ　ｆｉｎｄ　ｏｕｔ　ｔｈｅ　ｒｅｓｕｌｔ，　ｓｔａｒｉｎｇ　ｆｒｏｍ　２ｎｄ　ｗｅｅｋ，　ｈｏｗ　ｃａｎ　Ｉ modify the query?　　Ｉｎ　ｔｈｉｓ　ｃａｓｅ，　ｉｔ　ｓｈｏｕｌｄ　ｒｅｔｕｒｎ 1|2, 2|1 since a,b appear in 2nd week while only 1 appear in 3rd week.

Comment: I tried to change to "set @week_id := 2 ..........WHERE week_id >=2.....", but it gave me 1|3, 2|1

Comment: @JJ `@week := 0` needs to stay as it is. To get week 2, change just `where week >= 1` to `where week >= 2`. I'll make sure it works in the next few hours.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but it gave me `1|4, 2|1`, but it supposed to return `1|2, 2|1`.  Hope you can test it.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks, but shouldn't the output be `1|2, 2|1` if start at week 2?  there are only 2 distinct users that come to the site on week 2.

Comment: @JJ OK. Finally fixed that bug too! I introduced a new variable at the top `@start_week` to make it easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason most of these answers are very over complicated, it doesn't need cursors or for loops or anything of the sort...

> I want to find out how many (same) people keep coming back in the
>   following week, when given a start week to look at.

If you want to know how many users for any week visited one week and then the week after for each future week:

```
SELECT visits.week, COUNT(1) AS [NumRepeatUsers]
FROM visits 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM visits AS nextWeek 
    WHERE nextWeek.week = visits.week+1 
      AND nextWeek.cookie = visits.cookie
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM visits AS searchWeek
    WHERE searchWeek.week = @week 
      AND nextWeek.cookie = visits.cookie
  )
GROUP BY visits.week
ORDER BY visits.week
```

However this will not show you diminishing results over time if you have 10 users in week 1, and then 5 different users visited for the next 5 weeks you would keep seeing 1=10,2=5,3=5,4=5,5=5,6=5 and so on, instead you want to see that 5=x where x is the number of users who visited every week for 5 weeks straight. To do this, see below:

```
SELECT visits.week, COUNT(1) AS [NumRepeatUsers]
FROM visits 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM visits AS nextWeek 
    WHERE nextWeek.week = visits.week+1 
      AND nextWeek.cookie = visits.cookie
  )
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT TOP 1 1 
    FROM visits AS searchWeek
    WHERE searchWeek.week = @week 
      AND nextWeek.cookie = visits.cookie
  )
  AND visits.week - @week = (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [Count]
    FROM visits AS searchWeek
    WHERE searchWeek.week BETWEEN @week+1 AND visits.week
      AND nextWeek.cookie = visits.cookie
  )
GROUP BY visits.week
ORDER BY visits.week
```

This will give you 1=10,2=5,3=4,4=3,5=2,6=1 or the like

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting one.

I try to work out when was the final week each person visited.
This is calculated as the first week on or after the start where the following week doesn't have a visit.

Once you know each user's final visiting week you just count up, for every week, the number of different users whose final visit was on or after that week.

```
SELECT wks.week, COUNT(cookie) as Visitors
FROM (SELECT a.cookie, MIN(a.week) AS FinalVisit
      FROM WeekVisits a 
           INNER JOIN WeekVisits FirstWeek
           ON a.cookie = FirstWeek.cookie
      WHERE a.week >= 1
        AND FirstWeek.week = 1
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                        FROM WeekVisits b
                        WHERE b.week = a.week + 1
                          AND b.cookie = a.cookie)
      GROUP BY a.cookie) fv
     INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT week 
      FROM WeekVisits
      WHERE week >= 1) wks
     ON fv.FinalVisit >= wks.week 
GROUP BY wks.week
ORDER BY wks.week
```

**EDIT**
-Thanks ypercube for noticing. I had also lost the group by from the "fv" query. Oops.
-I've removed the comments denoting parameters.
-I've removed the unnecessary distinct.
**EDIT** again
-Added in a extra stuff for FirstWeek because it didn't cope with starting on week 2

When I run this (admittedly on MS Access)

starting week 1 I get:

```
+------+----------+
| week | Visitors |
|  1   |   4      |
|  2   |   2      |
|  3   |   1      |
+------+----------+
```

starting week 2 I get:

```
+------+----------+
| week | Visitors |
|  2   |   2      |
|  3   |   1      |
+------+----------+
```

.. as expected.
(To start on week 2 you would change the 1 to 2 in the three places where it is compared with the week column)
The method seems sound but the syntax may need adjusting for MySQL.

Comment: You miss a parenthesis before `) fv`

Comment: Thanks.  But I run the query and returned `1|1`, is it right?

Comment: Definitely works, i tried. Another quick question if you don't mind, if my table has another field 'site_id', it can be 10, 11, 12 and it represents different website.  how can i modify the query so that it only look at particular site_id, for example, something like `IN (10,12)`

Comment: for example:  week, cookie, site_id:  `1 | a | 10,  1 | b | 11, 2 | a | 10` will return `1|1, 2|1`

Comment: I tried to add `AND a.site_id=10` after line 6 and `AND site_id=10` in line 16, but it didn't work, thanks again

Comment: another thing... it turns out that the week is formatted as '201105' which represents the 5th week of 2011.  so it comes a problem: how does sql know 201101 is right after 201052... sorry

Comment: Sites: You probably need **a.site_id = 10** and **FirstWeek.site_id = 10** in the where clause on line 6, plus **b.site_id = 10** on the where clause on line 10, plus **site_id = 10** in the where clause on line 16. I don't think MySQL allows the "WITH" construct for common table expressions which would make this much easier and more readable.

Comment: Weeks: I suppose if you only ever have 52 weeks in the year, not the occasional 53 once every 7 years then maybe you could amend the condition that says **b.week = a.week + 1** to say **(b.week = a.week + 1 OR (b.week % 100 = 52 AND a.week % 100 = 1 AND FLOOR(b.week / 100) = FLOOR(a.week / 100) +1 ))**

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's say your table is called `visits` and you are interested in week number `n`.  You want to know, for *every* week number `w >= n`, which users appear in *every* single such week `w`.

So how many such weeks are there?

```
select count(*)
from visits
where week >= n;
```

And in how many such weeks did each user visit?

```
select user, count(user)
from visit
group by user
where week >= n;
```

Suppose you have weeks 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 13, and you are interested in week 5.  So the first query above gives you 6, because there are 6 weeks of interest: 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, and 13.  The second query will give you, for each user, how many of those weeks they visited in.  Now you want to know for how many of those users the count is 6.

I think this works:

```
select user, count(user)
from visit
group by user
having count(user) = (
    select count(*)
    from visits
    where week >= n)
where week >= n;
```

but I don't have access to MySQL right now. If it doesn't work, then perhaps the approach makes some sense and sets you in the right direction.  EDIT: I will be able to test tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Use self-join:

```
SELECT ... FROM visits AS v1 LEFT JOIN visits AS v2 ON v2.week = v1.week+1
WHERE v2.week IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cookie
```

This will give you records of second and later visits.

But I think that better would be just to `GROUP BY cookie` which can get you number of visits per cookie; any number above 1 is a returning user.

Comment: ｔｈａｎｋ　ｙｏｕ　ｓｏ　ｍｕｃｈ．　　ｂｕｔ　ｉ　ｓｔｉｌｌ　ｃａｎｎｏｔ　ｇｅｔ　ｉｔ　ｔｏ　ｗｏｒｋ．　１）　ｗｈａｔ　ｄｏ　ｉ　ｐｕｔ　ａｆｔｅｒ　ＳＥＬＥＣＴ？　　２）　ｉｓ　ｔｈｅ　Ｇｒｏｕｐ　Ｂｙ　ｃｏｏｋｉｅ　ambiguous？

Comment: v2.week+1 should be v1.week+1

Comment: still doesn't know how to use this.  this solution seems to be the simplest one, it works, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, is not really straightforward but -as I have tested- it does solve your problem:

First we declare a stored procedure that will give us the visitor in a particular week separated by strings, you can use group_concat if you wish, but I did this way -take into account that group_concat has a text limit.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db`.`get_visitors_for_week`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_visitors_for_week`(id_week INTEGER, OUT result TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE should_continue INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c_cookie CHAR(1);
    DECLARE r CURSOR FOR SELECT v.cookie
                FROM visits v WHERE v.week = id_week;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET should_continue = 1;
    OPEN r;
    REPEAT
        SET c_cookie = NULL;
        FETCH r INTO c_cookie;
        IF c_cookie IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF result IS NULL OR result = '' THEN
                SET result = c_cookie;
            ELSE SET result = CONCAT(result,',',c_cookie);
            END IF;
        END IF;
        UNTIL should_continue = 1
    END REPEAT;
    CLOSE r;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then we declare a function to wrap that stored procedure, so we can call inside a query conveniently:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `db`.`concat_values`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `concat_values`(id_week INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE result TEXT;
    CALL get_visitors_for_week(id_week, result);
    RETURN result;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And then we must count the visitors that has come this week and last week -for each week of course-, we 'see' that by searching for our cookie string in the concatenated list. This is the final query:

```
SELECT
  v.week,
  SUM(IF(IFNULL(concat_values(v.week - 1)) OR INSTR(concat_values(v.week - 1),v.cookie) > 0, 1, 0)) AS Visitors
FROM (SELECT
        v.week,
        v.cookie,
        vt.visitors
      FROM visits v
        INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                      v.week,
                      concat_values(v.week) AS visitors
                    FROM visits v) AS vt
          ON v.week = vt.week) AS v
WHERE v.week >= 1
GROUP BY v.week
```

Substitue the condition `v.week >= 1` -the 1- for the week number you want to start from.